# vs code not opening in kali linux 2021.2

Tags: visual-studio-code, kali-linux

i have been using vs code since 8 months in kali linux but in different versions (like   2020.1 - 2021.1)

suddenly yesterday when i tried to open vs-code it doesn't open

i have tried uninstalling and installing several times,tried every solution i can find online
but still no use

i tried to solve the problem by trying to find where the problem rised and why is it rised.

i tried to do an update of my machine and microsoft repositories threw an error saying that signatures are invalid saying "NO_PUBKEY" and i changed my total operating system and installed a new version of **KALI LINUX 2021.2**

I done all the required updates and install vs code and when i click on the ***visual-studio-code*** it does nothing

neither does it open vs-code nor throw an error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. -- Launch VS Code in the shell and add the option `--verbose`. It might give you a hint what blocks it from starting. Please add new information like the output of this try by [edit]ing your question.

Answer (score 0):

You were probably using your "user: root" account while trying to open (the one with the skull). You have to create an personal account, otherwise vscode wont allow you to open it. Just create it and add root permissions.

> useradd -m yourname

> passwd yourname

> usermod -a -G sudo yourname

> chsh -s /bin/bash yourname

then log into that account and it should work fine.

Easiest way to download vscode in kali linux: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwHdRB0qLAg

Answer (score 0):

You can use VS code in root account by following per-requisite :

1. Go to the terminal and try opening the nano/usr/bin/code or vim/nano/usr/bin/code or emacs/usr/bin/code (You can use these commands accordingly to your editors which have installed on machine ).
2. Try to find out these line and comment out the whole line by adding # symbol before each line .

   ```
   # If root, ensure that --user-data-dir or --file-write is specified
   #if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
   #       for i in "$@"
   #       do
   #               case "$i" in
   #                       --user-data-dir | --user-data-dir=* | --file-write )
   #                               CAN_LAUNCH_AS_ROOT=1
   #                       ;;
   #               esac
   #       done
   #       if [ -z $CAN_LAUNCH_AS_ROOT ]; then
   #               echo "You are trying to start Visual Studio Code as a super user which isn't recommended. If this was intended, please add the argument \`--no-sandbox\` and specify an alternate user data directory using the \`--user-dat>
   #               exit 1
   #       fi
   #fi
   ```
3. Then go to the 2 last line there you will find the
   ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node "$@"
4. Just after the "$@" add --no-sandbox .
5. Press ctrl  +o and ctrl +x and hit enter .
6. Now try running the code by typing code in terminal .
7. if you want to run vs code without terminal then create its shortcut on the desktop,go to the properties under that you will find launcher option and in that you will find command option just erase the command and type code and save .
8. Now you will be able to access the code